# Assembler Timer/Clock

Tags: assembly, byte, clock, avr

I was wondering; isnt there an easier way to code this snippet?
I mean now the value is checked nibble by nibble but I have no clue why?

```
IncClock_Second:

inc clockS                                  ; increment timerS
cpi clockS, 0x5A                            ; Compare timerS to 60
breq incClockMinute                             ; If true, jump incMinute
swap clockS                                 ; swaps timerS register
cpi clockS, 0xA0                            ; compares timerS to 10
brlo endIncSec                              ; branches if lower then 10 to endIncSec

    incSecTen:          
        andi clockS, 0x0F                   ; does a logical AND with immediate on timerS
        inc clockS                          ; increments timerS
        swap clockS                         ; swaps timerS register back
    ret

endIncSec:
swap clockS                                 ; swap back
ret
```

Can't I just do this??

```
IncClock_Second:

inc clockS              
cpi clockS, 60                          
breq incClockMinute                                                 
 ret
```

if not why not? it just holds the current clock second am i right?
I need to send it to multisegment.java after and byte 0 1 is for clock hour left right followed by 2 3 for minute left minute right and 4 5 for second left second right.
I am not really splitting them here now am I right?

my sendTime is this:

```
sendTime:
cpi state, 4                                    ; compares with the mode register with 4
brge sendAlarm                              ; if this is greater or equal to 4 then branch to sendAlarm

mov temp, clockH                            ; copies the value of timerH to temp   temp = 0001 0010 = 18
swap temp                                   ; swap temp         tmp = 0010 0001
andi temp, 0x0F                             ; do a logical AND with immediate on temp 0010 0001
rcall convertToSeg                          ; calls converToSeg
rcall sendRS232                             ; Now lets send this ;)

mov temp, clockH                            ; copies the value of timerH again to temp
andi temp, 0x0F                             ; do a logical AND with immediate on temp
rcall convertToSeg                          ; calls converToSeg
rcall sendRS232                             ; Now lets send this ;)

mov temp, clockM                            ; copies the value of timerM to temp
swap temp                                   ; swap temp
andi temp, 0x0F                             ; do a logical AND with immediate on temp
rcall convertToSeg                          ; calls converToSeg
rcall sendRS232                             ; Now lets send this ;)

mov temp, clockM                            ; copies the value of timerMS again to temp
andi temp, 0xF                              ; do a logical AND with immediate on temp
rcall convertToSeg                          ; calls converToSeg 
rcall sendRS232                             ; Now lets send this ;)

mov temp, clockS                            ; copies the value of timerS to temp
swap temp                                   ; swap temp
andi temp, 0x0F                             ; do a logical AND with immediate on temp
rcall convertToSeg                          ; calls converToSeg
rcall sendRS232                             ; Now lets send this ;)

mov temp, clockS                            ; copies the value of timerS again to temp
andi temp, 0x0F                             ; do a logical AND with immediate on temp
rcall convertToSeg                          ; calls converToSeg
rcall sendRS232                             ; Now lets send this ;)

mov temp, settings                          ; Copies the value of settings to temp SIDE NOTE : dubbelpunt aan
rcall sendRS232                             ; Now lets send this ;)

endSendTime:
ret
```

Thanks in advance if you need more snippets please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assembly Alarm Clock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919830/assembly-alarm-clock)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the variable is not plain binary, rather it's BCD (binary coded decimal). This means each nibble is storing a decimal digit. Notice how the overflow to 60 is checked by comparing to `0x5A`, meaning the tens are still `5` but the ones have gone out of range to `10`. In this case the seconds should be reset to `0x00` and the minutes incremented in a similar fashion.

The second part of the code checks for a more generic version, the ones overflowing from `9` to `10` that is when the value should be a multiple of `10`. It does this by swapping the nibbles and checking if the result is greater than or equal to `0xA0`. In this case, the high nibble is cleared (wrap around from `9` to `0`) and the low nibble (containing the tens) is incremented by 1. We know this will not overflow because of the earlier check against `0x5A`.

Instead of swapping you could just mask off the low nibble and perform the checks that way. Would be more readable and possibly shorter too.

```
    inc clockS
    mov temp, clockS
    andi temp, 0x0F
    cpi temp, 0x0A
    brne endIncSec
    cpi clockS, 0x5A
    breq incClockMinute
    subi clockS, -6 ; propagate to tens
endIncSec:
    ret
```

(I assume `temp` and `clockS` are registers.)